# Can't catch PDO exceptions using eloquent's capsule manager

Tags: php, exception, eloquent

I've got a class that extends the capsule manager of eloquent :

```
class Database extends \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager
```

Inside of it, I'm adding a connection in the constructor :

```
public function __construct()
{ 
    parent::__construct();

    try {
        $this->addConnection([
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => $server,
            'database' => $database,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
        ]);

        $this->setAsGlobal();
        $this->bootEloquent();

    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        exit("Can't connect to database");
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the catch is never called, if any of the database connection information is false, I get a `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException` and not the exit I'm looking to get.

I suppose the problem is due to me having my own class that extends of the capsule manager, but how do I catch the connection errors in my own class using eloquent?

EDIT : Traceback -

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/vendor/illuminate/database/Connectors/Connector.php:70 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/database/Connectors/Connector.php(70): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=mari...', 'root', 'root', Array) #1 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/database/Connectors/Connector.php(46): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createPdoConnection('mysql:host=mari...', 'root', 'root', Array) #2 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php(24): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=mari...', Array, Array) #3 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php(182): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector->connect(Array) #4 [internal function]: Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\Database\Connectors{closure}() #5 /var/www/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(918): call_user_func(Object(Closure)) #6 /va in /var/www/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php on line 664

Having the class looking like this, and extending the `select`, `update`, `insert` functions :

```
class Database extends \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager
{

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public static function select(string $query, array $params = [])
    {

    }

    public static function insert(string $query, array $params = [])
    {
    }

    public static function update(string $query, array $params = [])
    {
        return parent::update($query, $params);
    }

}
```

And then writing for example this :

```
new Database;
Database::update('XXX', []);
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the call to the parent constructor inside the try/catch? It seems logical to assume that the code causing the error must be in that constructor

Comment: @ADyson nice suggestion, unfortunately no, I still have the fatal error and no exit. Although, now with your suggestion, I have the error written 2 times, one beneath the other. Once as a fatal error, once a an array with `["code"]=> "E_ERROR"` and `["message"]=> "Uncaught PDOException...etc`

Comment: `addConnection()` doesn't connect to the database, it only registers the configuration. The `PDOException` must be coming from somewhere else, where the connection is actually opened (and fails).

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir it's coming from a class inside the vendor as you can see in my edit, but it's not initialized anywhere beside inside my constructor. Any idea how can I catch errors using my class?

Comment: How are you using the capsule manager? What does your class look like?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir question updated, if that answers your question?

Comment: What does the whole stacktrace look like? Doesn't the exception come from `Database::update('XXX', []);`? Have you tried catching it here?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir unfortunately that's the whole stacktrace that I posted, I got nothing else. Each page got hundreds of DB calls, I can't try/catch all of them. The try/catch needs to be inside the class, which is what I'm looking to do but I can't figure out the correct way :/

Comment: Try overriding the `getConnection()` method and wrapping `parent::getConnection()`  in `try/catch`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir it was a good try, but returning `parent::getConnection()` doesn't actually give an error, it returns a `Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection` object which exists.